# FASTAPI, POSTGRESQL, asyncpg: asyncpg.exceptions.ConnectionDoesNotExistError: connection was closed in the middle of operation

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous, fastapi

i'm trying to connect FastAPI application with the PostgreSQL database within an asynchronous environment. I'm using the same server, but two different databases for asynchronous and non-asynchronous requests on Postgresql. And I get this error:

```
INFO:     Started server process [5848]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 856, in _read_ready__data_received
    data = self._sock.recv(self.max_size)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 677, in lifespan
    async with self.lifespan_context(app) as maybe_state:
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 566, in __aenter__
    await self._router.startup()
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 654, in startup
    await handler()
  File "C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒\Workspace\invest\users\app\main.py", line 18, in on_startup
    await create_db_and_tables()
  File "C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒\Workspace\invest\users\app\database\__init__.py", line 23, in create_db_and_tables
    async with async_engine.begin() as conn:
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\contextlib.py", line 175, in __aenter__
    return await self.gen.__anext__()
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\engine.py", line 1061, in begin
    async with conn:
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\base.py", line 125, in __aenter__
    return await self.start(is_ctxmanager=True)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\engine.py", line 270, in start
    await greenlet_spawn(self.sync_engine.connect)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 190, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3268, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 170, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 903, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 936, in connect
    await_only(creator_fn(*arg, **kw)),
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 125, in await_only
    return current.driver.switch(awaitable)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 185, in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py", line 2329, in connect
    return await connect_utils._connect(
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connect_utils.py", line 991, in _connect
    conn = await _connect_addr(
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connect_utils.py", line 828, in _connect_addr
    return await __connect_addr(params, True, *args)
  File "c:\users\▒▒▒▒▒\workspace\invest\users\venv\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connect_utils.py", line 876, in __connect_addr
    await connected
asyncpg.exceptions.ConnectionDoesNotExistError: connection was closed in the middle of operation
```

**This is my code in database.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, async_sessionmaker, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

from ..config import config, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASS, DB_PORT, DB_USER


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{config[DB_USER]}:{config[DB_PASS]}@{config[DB_HOST]}:{config[DB_PORT]}/{config[DB_NAME]}"

async_engine = create_async_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,
    pool_pre_ping=True,
)

AsyncSessionLocal = async_sessionmaker(
    async_engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False, class_=AsyncSession
)

Base = declarative_base()

async def create_db_and_tables():
    async with async_engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
```

**Could somebody tell me how to deal with this problem? It worked on SQLite.**